# Cannot connect the python application with sockets properly to a public IP address

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, ngrok

I developed a simple chat app that allows users to connect to a server and chat. This is the code for the server.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

def log_file_name():
    n = str(datetime.now())
    m = n.replace(':','_').replace(' ','---')
    l = m.split('.')[0]
    l = f'{l}.txt'
    return l

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 10001
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#print(type(server_socket))
server.bind((HOST, PORT))
server.listen()
print('server_initiated...')
logfile = os.path.join('logs', log_file_name())
with open(logfile, 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(f'{str(datetime.now())} log file initiated!\n\n')

clients = []
nicknames = []

#broadcast
def broadcast(message):
    #print(clients)
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)
        
def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            #print(f'{nicknames[clients.index(client)]} says {message}')
            broadcast(message)
            with open(logfile, 'a') as fh:
                fh.write(f"{nicknames[clients.index(client)]} says {message.decode('utf-8')}\n")
            
            
        except Exception:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            left_nick = nicknames[index]
            leaving_notes = f"{left_nick} just left the chat!!  --  time {str(datetime.now()).split(' ')[1].split('.')[0]}"
            broadcast(leaving_notes.encode('utf-8'))
            with open(logfile,'a') as fh:
                fh.write(f'{leaving_notes}\n')
            nicknames.remove(left_nick)
            break
        
#recieve message
def recieve():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        #print(dir(client))
        #print(client._io_refs)
        #print(f'Connected with {str(address)}!!')
        with open(logfile, 'a') as fh:
            fh.write(f'Connected with {str(address)}!!\n')
        client.send('Nickname'.encode('utf-8'))
        nickname = client.recv(512).decode('utf-8')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)
        #print(f'from 1st step clients are {clients}')
        #print(f'Nickname of the client is {nickname}')
        with open(logfile, 'a') as fh:
            fh.write(f'Nickname of the client is {nickname}\n')
        broadcast(f'Notice from server!! {nickname} just connected to the server!\n'.encode('utf-8'))
        client.send(f'Connected to the server as {nickname}\n'.encode('utf-8'))
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()
        
recieve()
```

Then I exposed that port to public using ngrok (ngrok http 10001), and it generated a public ip for me.

I coded a simple client gui using tkinter and I tried to connect the socket in to to above ngrok server I got. But I cannot broadcast messages. When I try to broadcast a message the GUI automatically closes. The reason is it meets a ConnectionAbortError.

Code for client-

```
import threading
import tkinter
import socket
import tkinter.simpledialog
import tkinter.scrolledtext
import os

#HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
#PORT = 10001
HOST = '3a7d-2402-4000-1245-cd8a-5d64-9c3f-25a3-79a4.in.ngrok.io'
PORT = 443  #or 80

class Client:
    def __init__(self,host,port):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))
        
        msg = tkinter.Tk()
        msg.withdraw()
        
        self.nickname = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('Nickname', 'Please enter a nickname', parent=msg)
        self.gui_done = False
        self.running = True
        gui_t=threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        recieve_t=threading.Thread(target=self.recieve)
        gui_t.start()
        recieve_t.start()
        
    def gui_loop(self):
        self.win = tkinter.Tk()
        self.win.configure(bg='lightgray')
        
        self.chat_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text='Chat:', bg='lightgray')
        self.chat_label.config(font=('Arial',12))
        self.chat_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        
        self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
        self.text_area.pack(padx=20,pady=5)
        #self.text_area.config(state='disabled')
        
        self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text='Message:', bg='lightgray')
        self.msg_label.config(font=('Arial', 12))
        self.msg_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        
        self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height=3)
        self.input_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        
        self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, text='Send', command=self.write)
        self.send_button.config(font=('Arial', 12))
        self.send_button.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        
        self.gui_done = True
        self.win.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.stop)
        self.win.mainloop()
        
    def write(self):
        message = f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"
        #print(message)
        self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        self.input_area.delete('1.0','end')
        
    def recieve(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                print(message)
                if message == 'Nickname':
                    self.sock.send(self.nickname.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    if self.gui_done:
                        #print('I hit here often')
                        self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                        self.text_area.insert('end', message)
                        self.text_area.yview('end')
                        #self.text_area.config(status='disabled')  #never use this inside a loop, disabled blocks the code....
            except ConnectionAbortedError:  #when closed the window I come here..
                print('Am i here?')
                #break
                os._exit(0)
                #break
                
            except:
                break
                print('Error')
                self.sock.close()
                break
    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.sock.close()
        exit(0)

client = Client(HOST, PORT)
```

If you run this please make sure to create a directory called *logs* to save the log of communication. Or else it will give an error(You can try it on localhost). I think I am doing something that doesn't work here. Can you point it out to me? or can you give me an alternative way of doing it?

Comment: What's the significance of http here? You are using port 443 or 80? What does `ngrok http 10001` do?

Comment: It opens an http webserver that maps 10001 port in localhost to the web address 3a7d-2402-4000-1245-cd8a-5d64-9c3f-25a3-79a4.in.ngrok.io port 80

Comment: What you need is TCP service, so try `ngrok tcp 10001` instead.